# applying stylesheet to descendant with exception

Tags: stylesheet

I want to apply following css to all hyperlinks except one of them, how do I apply this excception?

`#top-toolbar .top-toolbar-tabs li a {...}`

so all a tags inside li tags inside ul with class top-toolbar-tabs, will have this css except one of them. How?

Comment: Saying "except one of them" isn't at all useful. Which one of them, how do you identify that it should be different, etc?

Comment: atually it renders on run time. so The only way is to change the style by javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add additional classes to the `a` tags? If you can, just add a class `style_it` to the ones you want to style. Then your css is like this:

`#top-toolbar .top-toolbar-tabs li a.style_it {...}`

and HTML:

```
<a href="" class="style_it">1</a>
<a href="">2</a>
<a href="" class="style_it">3</a>
```

1 and 3 get your style and 2 does not.